# Tomcat Error - FAIL - Application at context path /petclinic could not be started

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have browsed the similar questions and come up with nothing so here goes.  I installed Tomcat 7 and then compiled the PetClinic app with maven.  I deployed it to Tomcat successfully.   I have since undeployed and recompiled the war file and deployed it and now it throws the error FAIL - Application at context path /petclinic could not be started. Here are the first few lines of the log file.  Please advise.  Thanks.

```
    Sep 23, 2012 2:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 23, 2012 2:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager$PrivateManager
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:34)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1255)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager$PrivateManager
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:34)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
```

Q: Are you using log4j (that's what I'd recommend) or slf4j?

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Make sure the relevant .jar files (heck - why not include *both* log4j and slf4j .jars) are in your WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder.

2) Make sure you have only *one* version of log4j in your Tomcat environment (it's  possible that maybe you might have two, conflicting, versions of the .jar laying around).

Comment: Hey paulsm4 Thank you! for responding.  I grabbed log4j.jar and dropped it in the deployed app's WEB-INF/lib folder and tried to start it and got the same message.

Comment: I checked and com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15, log4j-1.2.17, com.springsource.slf4j.log4j-1.5.6 are all in there.

Comment: Q: What does "in there" mean? Have you checked the *entire* Tomcat install folder, or just your particular war's WEB-INF/lib?  Here's the SpringSource/SLF4J manifest: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.slf4j.log4j&version=1.5.6.  SUGGESTION: *delete* one of your log4j .jar's (your choice which), and *look again* for any other (potentially conflicting) .jars.  Reboot your server, restart Tomcat, and try again.  Good luck!